# Matlab won't start GUI

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, matlab

I have an issue with ma Matlab R2015b installation on kubuntu 16.04. 
The problem is I can't start it in GUI mode. I'm completely clueless, does anybody have an idea what to do?

I'm trying to launch it from command line by

```
matlab -desktop
```

And I always get the commandline version. It used to work for some time but then stopped. Probably when upgrading from 15.10.

The complete response:

```
   MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
   No protocol specified

                                       < M A T L A B (R) >
                             Copyright 1984-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.
                              R2015b (8.6.0.267246) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                         August 20, 2015


    To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
    For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.


    Student License -- for use by students to meet course requirements
    and perform academic research at degree granting institutions only.

    >>
```

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Do you get any error from that code?

Comment: I get error for plot()

>> plot(x,Y)                                                                                                  
Warning: MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL. For   
more information, click <a href="matlab:opengl('problems')">here</a>.